# Can't upload image to server swift

Tags: swift, post, server, nsurlsession

I'm trying to upload an image to the server. As for now, I get an error response which checks if name='image', and the error means that it's not. The line where I set it is this:

```
body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='image'; filename='test.jpg'")
```

my full code of the POST request is this: I do get a 200 and the only problem is with the name parameter which I really can't figure out.

```
    func imageUploadRequest()
{

    let stringUrl = "http://88.162.41.55/app_backend/public/api/v1/image?_r=1836486547600309"
    let URL = NSURL(string: stringUrl.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    request.setValue("Bearer \(jwtToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)

    if(imageData == nil)  {
        print("image data is nil")
        return
    }

    let body:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name='image'; filename='test.jpg'")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: image/jpg")
    body.appendData(imageData!)
    body.appendString("\r\n")

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    request.HTTPBody = body

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }            
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(" response = \(responseString!)")

        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            print("json", json)
        } catch {
            print("bad things happened")
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Use NSURLSession, posted a solution to a similar problem the other month.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't that what I'm using?

Comment: Yes; I am sorry, your right you are using the correct syntax. Here a sample of a similar call I am making; with a few key differences, notably in the way I am encoding the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Sample NSURLSession

```
func getMetaData(lePath:String, completion: (string: String?, error: ErrorType?) -> Void) {
// **** get_metadata ****
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata")!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("Bearer ab-blah", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("path", forHTTPHeaderField: lePath)
    let cursor:NSDictionary? = ["path":lePath]
    do {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(cursor!, options: [])
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData
        print("json ",jsonData)
    } catch {
        print("snafoo alert")
    }

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            completion(string: nil, error: error)
            return
        }
        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        //print("Body: \(strData)\n\n")
        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers);


            completion(string: "", error: nil)
        } catch {
            completion(string: nil, error: error)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}
```